# Windows 8.1 can't connect to NAS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, nas

I've setup a NAS File Server over my Fritz!Box 7390.

Windows XP and Debian can mount it easily, however windows 8.1 cannot.

I can see my NAS in my Network Tab in the Windows Explorer, however it's listed as "Other Device" and clicking on it simply opens the configuration page of my fritzbox (it's a wlan router).

When I manually enter the IP of the NAS it says it cannot connect to it (Error code: 0x80070035).

Windows diagnostic tools won't find anything, as always, and I srsrly don't know what else to do.

Comment: Which antivirus are you using on your Win8 and do you have the same problem if you disable your AV?

Comment: something picked up from sevenforums: Click on the "START" button, select "CONTROL PANEL", and go into "DEVICE MANAGER". Click on "NETWORK ADAPTERS", then click on "VIEW", and select "SHOW HIDDEN DEVICES". In the expanded view you will see a long list of numbered "MICROSOFT 6to4 ADAPTER". My Windows 7 Professional desktop had 200 of them. Right click and select "DELETE" on all but 1 of them. You can only do 1 at a time so it does take a while. When you have only 1 left, restart computer and enjoy being able to see your other network computers, including HOMEGROUP files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the adapter settings and check to see that on the properties of the adapter, that "Client for Microsoft Networks" is installed.  This is in the list that contains Internet Protocols. This was missing from my adapters, took 10 seconds to add it in and reboot, then everything was fine.